# Cannot find xpath Html Agility Pack C#

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape data from this website in C#:

[https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/si_weighting_recommendations.jhtml?tab=sirecommendations](http:////*[@id=%22contentContainer%22]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2])

When I copy the xPath in Chrome Browser for a certain sector, I get:

```
//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
```

When I use the xPath Finder and enter in the xPath for that item, it can't find it. Why is this?

I am using HTML Agility Pack, so I know that it doesn't like to use the "tbody" node, so I've taken that out, however I'm still getting an error when trying to pull this node. I can only get down to the following xPath

```
//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div[2]/div[4]/div/section/div/div/div/div
```

Is there any way I can grab this information off this webpage using HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: Use elements attributes like id or class in your XPath instead of mentioning detailed path of the element like that. Which element do you want to get from the above link?

Comment: Tried that. For some reason the source that HTML Agility Pack comes up with is different from the source Chrome Browser gets

Comment: @jDave1984 Commonly, that happen because parts of page are dynamically generated by javascript. If this is the case, unfortunately, you need to find another tool that can run the script and HtmlAgilityPack solely can't help

Comment: @har07 Yeah that's what it looks like. Its all good. The sectors have their own site so I can pull the data I need from them.